# Delete 25 million records from 2.4 billion rows using in Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-delete

I'm using Java Spring scheduler to run deletion for 1000 rows in loop for 1000 times for this.

the main concern about it is, The execution plan for each successive loop will do more work than the previous loop. the `cityNames` is **not an indexed.**

**Table Structure**

```
ID |  NAME  | CITY | ADDRESS | ZIP
```

**my approach**

I'm using below select query to fetch them for ID's

```
SELECT * 
FROM per.person 
WHERE city IN (:cityNames) LIMIT :limit"
```

then use CRUDRepository inbuilt `deleteByIdInBatch(ids)` methods to delete all those in single query using those retrieved Ids

Is there any better way than this?

Comment: yes, just use delete statement with where condition

Comment: Seems like you need a stored procedure and cursor. I.e. minimize jdbc network latency between java application code and database.

Comment: A single DELETE might be faster because it has to read this large table just once. You could first create an index on the city name, and then delete city by city.

Comment: For any non-trivial data related jobs only use native standard SQL, the lingua franca for data management. What value CRUDRepository or whatever else logic tier tool could bring except proprietary syntax and a massive amount of meaningless roundtrips?

Comment: Just write `DELETE FROM per.person WHERE city in (:cityNames)` instead of retrieving everything and then issue a delete.

Comment: Of course there is a better way.  But is it worth the effort to find it?  Probably not.  By the time you find and test it, the job will already be done.  Is there actually a problem with the current way?  Is it done often enough to matter?  Why screw around with LIMIT rather than just doing what you want to do?

Comment: @Frank Heikens Index will affect delete, yes it will speed up the selection in the same time delete will bring to B-tree index structure rebuild and re-balance. So result will be log2 slower then delete without index.

Comment: since the system that we use in java has a distributed (hazelcast) caching, the data has to be removed from cache too,  the cache stores in form of partitions and i have to remove data finding the partition and then execute DELETE at last using the primary key IDs, the problem with the direct delete is for the subsequent deletes the execution time is going to increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in outlines several approaches.

> Instead of using a huge IN-list, join on a VALUES expression, or if the list is large enough, use a temp table, index it, then join on it.

That thread links to several other references showing these strategies.